# Recurrent Neural Networks / LSTM Structure: c_t+1 = i_t * k_t + c_t * f_t

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Source on LSTMs at: https://medium.com/@jon.froiland/recurrent-neural-networks-part-6-d585c7af8923

```
output_t = activation(dot(state_t, Uo) + dot(input_t, Wo) + dot(C_t, Vo) + bo)
i_t = activation(dot(state_t, Ui) + dot(input_t, Wi) + bi)
f_t = activation(dot(state_t, Uf) + dot(input_t, Wf) + bf)
k_t = activation(dot(state_t, Uk) + dot(input_t, Wk) + bk)
```

You obtain the new carry state (the next c_t) by combining i_t, f_t, and

```
c_t+1 = i_t * k_t + c_t * f_t
```

I understand the need for f_t and i_t OR k_t, however, I don't intuitively understand why both i_t and k_t are necessary. Each contains the same input data (state_t and input_t). Is it for implementation purposes to help align with c_t * f_t in terms of matrix dimensionality? Any thoughts on this are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the classical LSTM, these two have different activation functions. `i_t` is called the input gate with a sigmoid activation function, `k_t` are also called the "candidate values" with a tanh activation functioni. I have also read the terms input and "input" and "input modulation" (e.g. [Gal & Ghahramani](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/6241-a-theoretically-grounded-application-of-dropout-in-recurrent-neural-networks.pdf)). To cite the wonderful [blog post](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) by Christopher Olah on LSTMs,

> The next step [after the forget gate layer] is to decide what new information we’re going to store in the cell state. This has two parts. First, a sigmoid layer called the “input gate layer” decides which values we’ll update. Next, a tanh layer creates a vector of new candidate values, C~t, that could be added to the state. In the next step, we’ll combine these two to create an update to the state.

The input gate layer he is referring to is your `i_t`, the candidate values are `k_t`. Basically,

> the sigmoid layer tells us which (or what proportion of) values to update and the tanh layer tells us how to update the state.

(citing Jann Krynauw in the blog post discussion). Be sure to check out that post, I found it very helpful to understand LSTMs!

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate the explanation.